# why wordpress website show bad request of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I put the following jquery codes on page footer.php in theme folder :

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 jQuery('body').on('click', 'a.closebtn', function(e) {
       jQuery(document.body).removeClass('commentpopupdata');
        return false;

    });
   jQuery( ".commentCountDiv" ).click(function() {
    var product_id = jQuery(this).attr("com_productid");
    jQuery(document.body).addClass('commentpopupdata');
    jQuery.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
                            type:'POST',
                            data:'action=productscomments&product_id='+product_id,
                             success:function(results)
                                {
                                     jQuery(".upcomproduct").html(results);
                                 }
                         });
                 return false;
});
});
```

error message : POST http://rentsss.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

how to fix the error?

Comment: Usually need to send a `nonce` to wp ajax. Also make sure action in your wp functions is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem at this line:

`data:'action=productscomments&product_id='+product_id,`

the action is actually the Ajax handler which you must  defined in your hook

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_function' );`

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_function' );`

notice after the `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` we added our action value which is my_action

As in your script you have defined the action is equal to `productscomments&product_id='+product_id,` WordPress trying to find an action with that name and when it's not available you will get `400 (Bad Request)`

so for example if you want to recount the comment when the user click on the `commentCountDiv` button your code should look like this :

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery('body').on('click', 'a.closebtn', function(e) {
    jQuery(document.body).removeClass('commentpopupdata');
        return false;

    });
jQuery( ".commentCountDiv" ).click(function() {
    var product_id = jQuery(this).attr("com_productid");
    jQuery(document.body).addClass('commentpopupdata');
    jQuery.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
            type:'POST', 
            data:{
                'action': 'my_action', //here is your function name
                'product_id': 'product_id',
            },
                success:function(results)
                {
                    jQuery(".upcomproduct").html(results);
                    }
                });
        return false;
});
});
```

and your php code should look like the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {

    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    echo $product_id;
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

[Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)